# Repaint JPanel with images from video

Tags: java, swing

There is a need to create a video player where i can edit frames.
I am trying to create a JFrame and added JPanel inside.
I need to capture images from a video and display the same in JPanel.  I
cannot use the custom controls of Java Swings.  I am trying to call
repaint inside for loop. However, paintComponent is called only for the first time.

```
public class MainPaint extends JFrame {

    
    static{ System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }
    PaintPanel paintPan = null;
    
    public MainPaint() {
        setTitle("Video Panel");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

         paintPan = new PaintPanel();
        JButton testButon = new JButton("Display Video");
        add(paintPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(testButon, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        testButon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    paintPan.updateGraphics(50, 50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainPaint();
    }
}

class PaintPanel extends JPanel {

    

    public PaintPanel() {
       // setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    }

    int count = 0;
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D)  g.create();
       
        graphics2d.drawImage(image, null, 0, 0);
        graphics2d.dispose();
       
    }

    BufferedImage image = null;
    public void updateGraphics(int length, int width) throws InterruptedException {
      
        File selectedFile = new File("C:\\image_test\\Opencvs\\data\\test.mp4");
        
        String filePath = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
        
        VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture(filePath);// Load video using the videocapture method//
         Mat frame = new Mat(); // define a matrix to extract and store pixel info from video//
        Mat dst = new Mat ();
        
        while (true) {
            
            if (cap.read(frame)) {
     
                    image = (Mat2bufferedImage(frame)); //setting the results into a frame and initializing it //
                
                     repaint();
                     Thread.currentThread().wait(100);
                    
        }// if loop
            }   // while loop   
        
    }
    
    private static BufferedImage Mat2bufferedImage(Mat image) {   // The class described here  takes in matrix and renders the video to the frame  //
        MatOfByte bytemat = new MatOfByte();
        Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", image, bytemat);
        byte[] bytes = bytemat.toArray();
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `VideoCapture` class is not a native Java class.  Pointing to the source and explaining how this class works would be helpful.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Comment: org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture. This is opencvs java biding..

Comment: I see there are [tutorials](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for using OpenCV with JavaFX.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in:

```java
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    try {
        paintPan.updateGraphics(50, 50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    repaint();
}
```

especially in the call of blocking method (it contains endless loop):

```
paintPan.updateGraphics(50, 50);
```

is called directly in the event dispatch thread (EDT). When you block this thread then really there can't be any update because it is the thread that actually paints everything.

To release the EDT you can call this method from another thread, e.g. you can create new and start it to execute your method:

```java
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    new Thread(() ->{
        paintPan.updateGraphics(50, 50);
    }).start();
}
```

This isn't the perfect solution, but probably a good starting point.
I would recommend you to read few books so you can improve the code above on your own:

- Filthy Rich Clients: Developing Animated and Graphical Effects for Desktop Java Applications
- Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship

Comment: Method `updateGraphics` calls method `repaint`. Calling `repaint` from a thread which is **not** the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) may cause problems.

Comment: @Abra hmm, repaint may be called from any thread: _To enable app-triggered painting, the AWT provides the following java.awt.Component methods to allow programs to asynchronously request a paint operation_ - from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html

Comment: even though repaint itself isn't a problem to be called from any thread: not so sure about the rest of the method - it seems to be reading and setting an image field which then is used in painting .. that's a recipe for problems without proper thread management